# Modeline artefacts around powerline arrows

Tags: mode-line, powerline

I'm using vanilla `powerline` with `solarized` theme:

```
(require 'powerline)
(powerline-center-theme) 
(load-theme 'solarized-light t)
```

And I get these artefacts (the *malformed* and sticking-slightly-above-modeline arrows), both when loading a theme after:
[image]

... or before `powerline`:
[image]

It happens in other themes as well, so `solarized` likely isn't at fault. Have you encountered this issue or would guesstimate what might cause it (e.g. `(global-linum-mode 0)`)?

Emacs 24.4, OS X 10.10.3

Comment: Try loading your theme before powerline.

Comment: Is the artifact at issue the convex/concave arrow shape?  If so, that is exactly what the author of that library intended (in my opinion).

Comment: @Jordon, loading a theme beforehand doesn't help.

Comment: @lawlist, no, the arrows are expected, but without the glitches. Try zooming in.

Comment: Ah, yes -- zooming in does indeed show the artifacts of which you speak.  If you `force-mode-line-update`, do the artifacts disappear?  You may be interested trying the latest version of the public release of Emacs for OSX -- i.e., 24.5 -- not much point trying to troubleshoot an earlier version (in my opinion) when a more recent stable public release is readily available.

Comment: @lawlist, `force-mode-line-update` didn't help. Hopefully Emacs 25 fixed this. (Although in that case surely I would've found others with this very same issue, but didn't. Maybe I'm the only one bothered by it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `(setq ns-use-srgb-colorspace nil)`